# Can A/B be a better variable than separate A, B in linear regression?

Tags: econometrics, regression

While learning Econometrics, I got curious to know whether `A/B` can make a better variable than separate `A` and `B`, when constructing a linear regression model.

Variables are often changed to more appropriate form in linear regression like making it log(x) or changing its scale for better interpretation. So I thought, why not try taking a ratio of two variables and get rid of the original two? (To avoid multicollinearity of course.)

For an example, let's say I'm interested in stock price and make a linear regression on it. Would it be better to include original `book value` and `market value` as two separate variables in my model or make them into one variable like `book value/market value`? or would it depend on the situation/purpose?